# Using the fact that a subset $S$ of $T$ is open if the inverse is an open subset of $X$ to find quotient topology.

Tags: general-topology

Good day, I am currently preparing for finals and I'm uncertain on how to find the quotient topology. Here's the example I'm working on:
$T=\{0,1\}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\to Y$ with $f(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x\geq0$.
Here's my thinking. The subsets of $T$ are as follows:
$\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\},\emptyset$.
So I need to find the inverse of each and check if they are open:

$f^{-1}(0)=(-\infty,0)$ which is open...possibly?

$f^{-1}(1)=[0,\infty)$ which I think is closed.

$f^{-1}(\{0,1\})=\mathbb{R}$ which is open.

So I believe the quotient topology is $\{0\},\{0,1\},\emptyset$
My struggle, clearly, is on recognizing the inverse and checking if it's open. Any help is appreciated.
(I apologize for the syntax errors, I'm still learning the input)

Comment: What you have done is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertions are correct. Of course you need to note too that $f^{-1}[\{1\}] = [0,\infty)$ is not only closed, but also *not open* (which is not the same, sets can be neither, or both open and closed). So $\{1\}$ is closed and not open, so $\{0\}$ is then automatically (as its complement) open and not closed.
You never need to check $\{0,1\}$ or $\emptyset$, they are always open by the definition of a topology (and also by the inverse image definition, as $f^{-1}[Y] = X$ for any $f:X \rightarrow Y$, and always $f^{-1}[\emptyset] = \emptyset$).

The resulting topology is indeed $\{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{0,1\}\}$. This is called the Sierpinski topology on $\{0,1\}$. It is a $T_0$ but not $T_1$, if you know separation axioms.